# How to let client Upload and Download files from S3 without compromising credentials

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am creating a file sharing kind of web site (something like wetransfer). I was thinking of using S3 for storage and I want to use different hosting solution instead of EC2 so my web server will be in a different host outside amazon cloud. In order to reduce bandwidth consumption I will need to someway let clients to download and upload files directly from the client (browser).

I was looking at [S3 documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html) which explained how to directly upload file to S3 from browser client. It looks like we are pretty much exposing all details of my s3 credentials where some can easily look into details and abuse.

Is there any way I can avoid this by something doing something like allow users to upload/download files with a temporary credentials?

Comment: I deleted my answer because I realized you want the client to upload. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was looking at S3 documentation which explained how to directly upload file to S3 from browser client. It looks like we are pretty much exposing all details of my s3 credentials where some can easily look into details and abuse.

No, you're not. When used properly, the POST-based upload interface documented on that page only gives the user a limited-time authorization to upload one file matching various criteria (e.g, its name, size, MIME type, etc). It's quite safe to use.

Keep in mind that *your S3 access key is not sensitive information*. Exposing it to users is perfectly fine, and is in fact required for many common operations! Only the secret key needs to be kept private.

Comment: When you say "limited-time", is it default behaviour of service that expires and we need  to renew keys frequently or is there any control we have? where can I find details about this?

Comment: **Read the documentation page you linked to in your question!** All of this, and more, is explained there.

Answer (score 1):

Would an IAM User Role work? You should be able to create a user (which will have it's own UUID), give it readonly access to your S3 repository, and pass that user's credentials into your request policy, as well as content and key rules.

If you want to grant all users read/write access, you can, though allowing those users access to specific files only, will be a bit more of a hassle.